# node-qrcode shows different code which is not varifiable at Server side using Otp.NET

Tags: c#, qr-code, one-time-password, google-authenticator, multi-factor-authentication

I am facing really strange issue and almost tried all possible combinitions so far to solve.
Unfortunately, the qr code which Google Authenticator app scans does not matches what Server side Otp.NET compute.

I used the same key, algorithm for generating Qr code at client side which is then scanned and transferred to server side for varification which gets failed. Folllowing is the source code for server side :

**Serve side Code. ( Key/Secret-Generation )** 
Used library : https://github.com/kspearrin/Otp.NET

```
 var otpSeed = KeyGeneration.GenerateRandomKey(OtpHashMode.Sha512);
 userIdentity.OTPSeed = otpSeed;

 customResponse.Add(TwoFASeedKey, Base32Encoding.ToString(key));
 customResponse.Add("OtpHashMode", "SHA512");
 customResponse.Add("Username", "alice@demo");
 customResponse.Add("Issuer", "demo Issuer");
```

While following code is being used to varify the OtpCode sent from client side.

```
public bool VerifyOtp(byte[] otpSeed, string otpCode) // otpSeed is the same secret which is being generated at the first step.
{
   var totp = new Totp(otpSeed, 30, OtpHashMode.Sha512, 6);
   return totp.VerifyTotp(otpCode, out var timeWindow, VerificationWindow.RfcSpecifiedNetworkDelay)
}
```

while following is the client side code which retrieves the above data as callback.

**Clientside**

Used Library to generate QRCode : (toDataURL) method used from https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode#createtext-options

```
 public void postLogin(){
      await this.oauthService.fetchTokenUsingPasswordFlow(username, password)
            .then(response => {

            const state = response['2FAState'];

       const seed = response['2FASeed'];
       const issuer = response['Issuer'];
       const userName = response['Username'];
       const otpHashMode = response['OtpHashMode'];


       this.username = userName;
       this.totpUri = this.makeTotpUri(seed, issuer, userName, otpHashMode);

       toDataURL(this.totpUri).then((data_url) => {
             this.otpQrCodeUrl = data_url; // This OtpQrCode bound with img src at HTML, which shows QR code png image at screen. Google Auth easily scans that image and shows the 6 digit code.
      });
  });
```

}

```
 private toTotpUri({ secret, accountName, issuer, algo, digits, period }:
 {
        secret: string; accountName: string; issuer: string;
        algo: string; digits: number; period: number;
 }) 
 {            
    return `otpauth://totp/${encodeURI(issuer || '')}
            :${encodeURI(accountName || '')}
            ?secret=${secret.replace(/[\s\.\_\-]+/g, '').toUpperCase()}
            &issuer=${encodeURIComponent(issuer || '')}
            &algorithm=${algo}
            &digits=${digits || 6}
            &period=${period || 30}`;
}

public makeTotpUri(seed: string, issuer: string, userName: string, otpHashMode: string): string {

    return this.toTotpUri({ secret: seed, accountName: userName, issuer, 
    algo: otpHashMode, digits: 6, period: 120 });
}
```

**Sample Secret generated from RandomKeyGenerator from Otp.NET**

```
ZYXHYYDP7TJBALMCFZBMLT7ALV3RU53UQ3JAULN7VGFVWEVDR4DLLHJAL7CFMZ4WDIDDWSMZ7O5D73L7KFIR6V3BYNTYJDCIG4KILRQ=
```

Note :
I tried to generate 6 digit Otp code manually at server side by using `ComputeHash` and varified it using Otp.Varify, it worked there. But when the code is scanned from Google Auth , its transferred code never get's matched at all. I have no idea why wrong code is being generated by QRCode.toDataURL method.
Any help would be really appreciated, as I am kinda stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

These code are time based - you have to make sure both the app and the server are synced to the correct time.

See my answer here to see if that helps?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107957/5234751