# Python3 pyotp timed generated codes not matching/the same on Aegis or Google Authenticator

Tags: python, python-3.x, one-time-password

The problems I'm having is the timed codes that pyotp generated are not the same. The following code is what I'm doing.

```py
key = "ThiskeyDoesNotChange"

totp = pyotp.TOTP(key)

uri = pyotp.totp.TOTP(key).provisioning_uri(name="therealOri", issuer_name="Genter")
#otpauth://totp/Genter:therealOri?secret=ThiskeyDoesNotChange&issuer=Genter
qrcode.make(uri).save('totp.png')
```

I will then scan the generated QRcode with my authenticator and it... at first glance looks like it'd work but when I try to verify the code it returns False.

```py
while True:
        print(totp.verify(input("Enter Code: ")))
```

The codes generated by `totp.now()` do not match what is shown in my authenticator.

I tried to look through stack for similar questions and found a couple. One with an answer and one without. I tried out the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978522/generated-codes-do-not-match-with-pyotp-sample), however I use Manjaro/Arch instead of ubuntu and I do have `ntp` but whenever I try to reload the service, "unit ntp.service isn't found". So that doesn't seem to help me. The other questions I found aren't helpful either and didn't work. I'm also doing this in python3 and not in c# or java, etc.

I am expecting the pyotp codes in my authenticator to be the same as the ones generated by `totp.now()`. I've tried using different libraries and the same thing keeps happening. I'm not entirely sure how to fix this issue or what the actual issue is. I can only assume some sort of timing is off? Idk.

Any help is very much appreciated and yes I know there are a few of the same questions that have been asked but they DO NOT help or work for me.

PS. I'd add more tags but I can't make new ones yet.

Comment: It's `ntp` (Network Time Protocol), not `npt`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, the typo has been fixed. My issue is still the same and I still need help.